# xamarin android Intent.getstringextra multiple variables

Tags: xamarin.android

i created 4 variables namely, "id", "name", "address", "age"
why does the value duplicates whenever i try intent.putextra

```
Context context = view.Context;  
Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(activity4));  
intent.PutExtra(activity4.id, joblist[position].id);  
intent.PutExtra(activity4.name, joblist[position].name);
intent.PutExtra(activity4.address, joblist[position].address);  
intent.PutExtra(activity4.age, joblist[position].age);
```

now the problem is when I do this.

```
string userId= Intent.GetStringExtra(id);  
string userName= Intent.GetStringExtra(name);  
string userAddress= Intent.GetStringExtra(address);  
string userAge= Intent.GetStringExtra(age);
```

when I put those strings in a textview, all four textviews would show the value for "age". as if all the data that was passed is only age. can anyone answer this? the output is like this

```
id= 12  
name= 12  
address= 12  
age= 12
```

Comment: what is `activity4`? Is it a class or instance?And could you provide more detailed codes like how did you get `joblist` initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Intent.Extras don't work like that when you use the typeOf() keyword

> typeOf is a C# keyword that is used when you have the name of the class. It is calculated at compile time and thus cannot be used on an instance, which is created at runtime. GetType is a method of the object class that can be used on an instance

Since it does not initialize like that your variables that you are assigning here are currently all null so the intent carries all the data in correspondence to null, Since the first value you enter with null is id you always get id

I would suggest you save the strings in either resource strings and reuse it or do something like this :

**First Activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(_context, typeOf(SecondActivity));
intent.PutExtra("Variable Name",string_to_be_sent);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Second Activity:**

```
//Receiving data inside onCreate() method of Second Activity
String value =Intent.GetStringExtra("Variable Name");
```

Comment: Hi, This is a fragment that holds recyclerview, this code is found on the itemclicklistener, i just want to pass multiple variables into another activity. Ill try your suggestion thanks

Comment: Are you trying to call an activity from a fragment ?

Comment: Yes this is perfect even in that case